# how to ignore list of attributes using the command line while clustering in weka?

Tags: weka

I am running a series of clustering analyses in weka and I have realized that automatizing it is the way to go if I want to get somewhere. I'll explain a bit how I am working.

- I do all the pre-processing manually in R and save it as a *csv* file, importing it in weka and saving it again as an *arff* file.
- I use weka's GUI, and in general I just open my data with in the *arff* file and go directly to the *clustering* tab and play around. (My experience using the **CLI** is limited).

I am trying to reproduce some results I've got by using the GUI, but now with commands in the **CLI**. The problem is that I usually ignore a list of attributes when clustering using the GUI. I cannot find a way of selecting a list of attributes to be ignored in the command line.

For example:

```
java weka.clusterers.XMeans \
-I 10 -M 1000 -J 1000 \
-L 2 -H 9 -B 1.0 -C 0.25 \
-D "weka.core.MinkowskiDistance -R first-last" -S 10 \
-t "/home/pedrosaurio/bigtable.arff"
```

My experience with weka is limited so I don't know if I am missing some basic understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data Preprocessing functions are called filters. 
You need to use filters together with cluster algorithm.
See below example.

```
java weka.clusterers.FilteredClusterer \ 
-F weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -V -R 1,5  \
-W weka.clusterers.XMeans  -I 10 -M 1000   -J 1000  -L 2 -H 9 -B 1.0 -C 0.25 \ 
-D "weka.core.MinkowskiDistance -R first-last" -S 10 \ 
-t "/home/pedrosaurio/bigtable.arff"
```

Here we remove attributes 1-5 then use xmeans.

Comment: Would you recommend another way of automatizing this without using the command lines? Just curiosity ...

Comment: Java code should be able to automate this. You can also do same thing with GUI but it is not automation.

Comment: The line you provided above do not work properly. I edited them as they work now but I need your approval

Comment: could you please approve the edits so the answer can be corrected?

Comment: @pedrosaurio I am sorry but I am not moderator. I can not approve edits. Also I do not understand why you remove acceptance. I answered your question. I know that it should work.

Comment: I removed the acceptance in order to call you attention as I thought you could accept editions on your own comments. The problem with your line is that the parameters on the filter should not have the `-V` as we want to remove attributes 1 and 5. Also for the parameters of the clusterer you need a `--` before the list of parameters. An example of a working line is :

Comment: `java weka.clusterers.FilteredClusterer   -p 1  -t input-file.csv -F "weka.filters.MultiFilter -F \"weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -R 1,5 \" " -W  weka.clusterers.XMeans -- -I 10 -M 1000 -J 1000 -L 2 -H 6 -B 1.0 -C 0.25 -D "weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last" -S 10 > outputfile.csv `

Comment: This command is slightly different but has the two main differences I mentioned... and works

Answer (score 0):

To ignore an attribute you have to do it from the distance function

Ignore attributes from command line (Matlab):

```
COLUMNS = '3-last'; % The indices start from 1, 'first' and 'last' are valid as well. E.g .: first-3,5,6-last
Df = weka.core.EuclideanDistance (); % Setup distance function.
Df.setAttributeIndices (COLUMNS); % Setup distance function.
```

Ignore attributes from GUI
[Ignore attributes from GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcLRP.png)

I do not understand why when someone asks how to ignore attributes all the answers say how to modify the dataset, using a filter in the preprocess section.